# How can I set the Text property of a TextBox to an static property of type double

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set the `Text` property of a `TextBox` to an static property which of type `double`. But obviously I'm getting an error:

> Invalid member type: expected type is 'string' actual type is 'double'

because it only accepts an string. How can I fix this? And why I don't get this error when I `Bind` to a non-static property which is also `double`?

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Static building:Building.FoundationHeight}"/>
```

Building is an static class and FoundationHeight is static property of type `double`.

**Solution:**

The question is a duplicate, I'll post the answer specific to this question here anyway:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static building:Building.FoundationHeight}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: You do not get this error when using a `{Binding}` because [`System.Windows.Data.Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) is a much more complex class that can handle (among other things) type conversions, while [`System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.staticextension.aspx) does not.

Comment: @JeanHominal Thanks, I was just curious, if this can be done this way?

Comment: Thank you so much, Sheridan. The link you posted solved the problem.

Comment: @Vahid Please do not add the answer to your question, but as an _answer_. After 48 hours, you will also be able to accept it.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Sure, I thought since this is a duplicate, now one will want it.

Comment: @Vahid Ah, my bad - if it stays closed you cannot add answers.. apologies!

Comment: @MathiasMüller I just realized that too :(